# Moment.js & Moment Timezone with data-attribute timezones

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timezone, momentjs

I've got a server-generated list of locations in `country/city` format, i.e.

```
<span class="location" data-timeZoneID="China/Beijing">Beijing</span>
<span class="location" data-timeZoneID="England/London">London</span>
```

**I'd like to use JS/Jquery and Moment Timezone do this:**

1. Pull the `data-timezone-` attribute from each item
2. Supply it to an instance of `moment.tz()`,
3. And append the element with the result, thus displaying the time in whatever locations are listed.

**EDIT**: I'm successfully pulling the data-attribute values with jQuery, but when I try to pass them to `moment().tz()`; the time is not converted and my local client time is displayed instead. When I manually enter an IANA time zone ID, the conversion happens (although it's still inaccurate). Any thoughts on why the value supplied from the `data-attribute` wouldn't be working?

This (sortof) works:

```
$(function(){
    $('.location').each(function() {
        var timeZone = $(this).data('timezoneid');
        var now = moment().tz('Africa/Tripoli').format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm");
        $(this).append( now );
    });
});
```

This doesn't (local time is displayed):

*HTML*

```
<span class="location" data-timeZoneID="Africa/Tripoli">Tripoli: </span><br />
<span class="location" data-timeZoneID="England/London">London: </span>
```

*JS*

```
$(function(){
    $('.location').each(function() {
        var timeZone = $(this).data('timezoneid');
        var now = moment().tz("'" + timeZone + "'").format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm");
        $(this).append( now );
    });
});
```

*jsFiddle*

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/gLNXd/47/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle that works

http://jsfiddle.net/93pEd/1/

Notice the 2 changes that I made:

```
 - London is Europe/London instead of England/London
 - the format is HH:mm instead of HH:MM
```

Comment: Wow. I have gone over the code probably 50 times, re-read the documentation, tried changing every line...thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It was a little hard to understand what your problem it but considering your "step by step"-list I would have done the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('.location').each(function() {
        var timeZone = $(this).data('timeZoneID');
        var now = moment().tz(timeZone).format('HH:MM');
        $(this).append( now );
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5xJ46/1/)

Comment: thanks for your response - when I run the code, the `timeZone` variable seems to return a value of `undefined` - you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gLNXd/41/

Comment: I can't use that fiddle since authentication is needed however I realized I was using moment incorrectly it should be something like this (function call on moment):
http://jsfiddle.net/hypzo/gLNXd/43/

Comment: I figured out the problem with the `undefined` data-attribute was the use of uppercase characters, which causes jQuery to interpret the string as multiple `data-attribute`s. Now it's displaying a time, but it's just my local time.